# Solving windowTranslucentStatus and adjustResize

Tags: android

I appreciate there's a number of questions around this but none of them seem to resolve the situation I find myself in. I've written a small test case to see if the community can support.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="#ff0000">
  </RelativeLayout>

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This snippet above, produces the following: -

[image]

when given a theme in the android manifest for this activity of: -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

So.. this is exactly what I would like, however when I open the keyboard, the following happens: -

(given that I have the following set in the manifest)

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

[image]

As you can see, the keyboard hides the edit text.

**This is where there's a number of other posts and confusion**

The recommendations seemed to be to set things like (and see the result for each): -

1. android:fitsSystemWindows in the root relativelayout

[image]

Great, this fixes the keyboard hiding the edit text but now the red bar at the top is moved downwards, which is not what I would like (see original image if needed)

2. Change `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`

[image]

As expected, the view pans and the top bar is lost.

At this point, I'm a bit lost without coming up with a hacky solution to resize and calculate on the fly, which feels very dirty.

**So given what I've posted above, does anyone have any solution to achieve the following: -**

- Translucent status bar (so the red panel sits behind it)
- red panel doesn't disappear when the soft keyboard is shown
- soft keyboard doesn't cover the text control

Let's also assume for arguments sake that colouring the status panel is not an option as I actually want to view the content behind the status panel, i.e. a map. I've used a red panel as an example.